# Is .live() timeout possible?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm using ajax to call a C# method in the code behind.

The process can take a long time to return an answer.  After stepping through my C# I'm positive the function is returning a `true` response.

My `.live()` click function accepts a true or false and displays the results.  As I mentioned I know the C# returns true.

So bottom line this function works as I intend when the response comes fairly quickly.  Is it possible in general for the `.live()` function to timeout and not respond?

Comment: `live` does not have a timeout, but ajax has a timeout which you can set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to sent a request to server in your [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler, if so

`live` does not have a timeout, but ajax has a timeout which you can set.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    timeout: 300000 //5 minutes
});
```

As a side note,
If you are using jQuery >= 1.7 use [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` since it is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

No. `live()` is an event listener.  You pass it a jQuery object/element/collection, and specify and event to bind those elements to. Also, `.live()` was deprecated some time ago, and shouldn't be used with jQuery 1.8 or 1.9, in favor of `.on()`.  `live()` will go on listening as long as the page is open.